# IQueryable returns inconsistent results

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities, devart

I have a relatively simple query which returns inconsistent results.

Having a collection of id's (approx 3300), I want to query for the objects which have a child with that id. The relationship between my types is 1 to n. I do this in batches of 500.

In my test, in the anonymous type in the Select clause, I have both `ChildType` and `ChildTypeId`. Starting with the 5th or 6th batch, my query returns wrong results. The batches run sequentially.

I am using .Net 4.6.1, EF6, DevArt 9.4.326 and Oracle 12c.

I will just post a summary of my code.

DB schema:

```
CREATE TABLE PARENT_TYPE
(
  "FK_CHLID_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE CHILD_TYPE
(
  "ID" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL
)
```

C# code:

```
public class ChildType
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class ParentType
{
  public ChildType ChildType { get; set; }
}

public void ProcessBatch(ISystemDataAccess dataAccess, long[] idsBatch)
{
  var queryResult = dataAccess.GetQuery<ParentType>()
                      .Where(p => idsBatch.Contains(p.ChildType.Id))
                      .Select(p => new
                      {
                        ChildId = p.ChildType.Id,
                        Child = p.ChildType,
                      }).ToList();

  if (queryResult.Any(qr => qr.ChildId != qr.Child.Id))
  {
    Debugger.Launch(); // will run in the 5th or 6th batch
  }
}
```

During the 5th or 6th batch the debugger will be launched.

Some remarks:
The data in db is consistent and is not causing the wrong results.
The erroneous results are in the Child property of the anonymous type and are different between runs. `ChildId` in the anonymous type is always as expected.
If I use a specific type in the Select clause, problem still occurs.

Does anyone experienced something similar? Is it caused by EF or DevArt in combination with contains()?
The solution would be to use the Id only, but I would like to know what is causing the issue.

Comment: Does Child objects contains some random Id value that doesn't match to ChildId? Or it is just zero? Maybe the object is not materialized for some reason. Or something wrong with internal caching mechanisms wich leads to incorrect results. Also you can try to do batch within loop in single application run and single batch within multiple runs and see what happens. Maybe you just need to dispose your *dataAccess* object or use new instance of it or something like that.

Comment: Please submit a small test project with the corresponding DDL/DML script for reproducing via https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html.